Sigmoid function that reaches its minimum/maximum values before infinity
I'm looking for a function that has the following characteristics:

x <= x0: y = y0
x >= x1: y = y1
x0 < x < x1: y0 < y < y1

For example, if x0 = 360, x1 = 1080, y0 = 15, y1 = 150:

x <= 360: y = 15
x >= 1080: y = 150
360 < x < 1080: 15 < y < 150

I'd like the curve to have an S-shape.
Is there such a function? I asked the GPTs and they suggested the logistic function, but this reaches its asymptotes at +/- infinity, which is not right for my needs (e.g. in my example, x == 360 gave y ~= 82, and only x == -Inf gave y == 15).

You could try with $$y_0+\frac{y_1-y_0}{\int_{x_0}^{x_1} e^{((t-x_0)(t-x_1))^{-1}},dt}\int_{x_0}^{\min{\max{x_0,x},x_1}} e^{((t-x_0)(t-x_1))^{-1}},dt$$ which is $C^\infty$ and monotone.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

A tunable example for the case $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0),(x_1,y_1)=(1,1)$ is
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} \frac{x^\gamma}{x^\gamma+(1-x)^\gamma}& 0 \leq x\leq 1\\ 0 & x<0 \\ 1, & x>1\end{array}\right.$$
with control parameter $\gamma\geq 1$.  To verify it behaves like a sigmoid function, note that for $x\in [0,1]$ we have
$$f(x)+f(1-x)=\frac{x^\gamma}{x^\gamma+(1-x)^\gamma}+\frac{(1-x)^\gamma}{x^\gamma+(1-x)^\gamma}=1$$
so $f$ is symmetric with respect to $x=1/2$. Additionally, the first derivative on this interval is
$$f'(x)=\gamma \frac{(1-x)^{\gamma-1}x^{1-\gamma}}{(x^\gamma+(1-x)^\gamma)^2}$$
Note that $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\in (0,1)$ and hence $f$ is increasing on this interval; additionally, $f'(0)=f'(1)=0$ and $f'(1/2)=\gamma$. Hence we get a sigmoid-style curve whose slope at the center increases with $\gamma$. (If $\gamma=1$ we have $f(x)=x$ for $0<x<1$, i.e., we're back to a piecewise-linear function.)
This can be applied to arbitrary $x_0,y_0,x_1,y_1$ by composing with appropriate linear transformations, i.e.,
$$y=y_0+(y_1-y_0)f\left(\frac{x-x_0}{x_1-x_0}\right)$$

One more general point: the 0,1 case indicated above (with increasing $f$) more generally matches the conditions for the CDF of a continuous random variable with support on [0,1]. Wikipedia’s list of probability distributions includes a gamut of RVs with bounded support, which thus yields a catalog of “bounded  sigmoid” functions.
